# Can't find library Google play billing or Extras

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager, play-billing-library

Referable links but didn't work for me:

- [Android Studo 3.0 SDK Manager, can't find Extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128673/android-studo-3-0-sdk-manager-cant-find-extras?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [I can't find Google Play Billing Library in the Android Studio SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831282/i-cant-find-google-play-billing-library-in-the-android-studio-sdk-manager)

**I'm use Android Studio 3.1.2**

I am trying to find **Google Play Billing Library** in this Studio but didn't find it.

Also i'm Put Library in build.gradle(app):

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
```

Gradle Build Successfull but didn't show the Google Play Billing Library in SDK Manager

### See below SDK Manager dialog Screenshot:

[image]

Below is **`build.gradle(app)`** :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: well according to documentation you just need to implement it in your .gradle file and integrate it using google console.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_java_kotlin#java

Comment: but if suppose i want to [implement like this link](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial) then waht ??

Comment: by the way you can still download and install billing library from sdk. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can't find billing library in your sdk is because according to [google official blog:](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/google-play-billing-library-10-released.html)

> you will find that Play Billing Library is available through Maven repository now that's why you can't find it on your sdk.

so now you start by adding billing library as a dependency. and then move ahead.

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
```

And also google have given the coding sample to get you started with:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/play-billing-codelab/#0

[Github Link](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/play-billing-codelab)

moreover you can find some explanation in this answer too:

[Why is the Google Play Billing Library not shown up in the SDK Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391543/why-is-the-google-play-billing-library-not-shown-up-in-the-sdk-manager?rq=1)

Comment: i'll check this but not there

Comment: @MohammadAli can you tell me which gradle version you are using ? Ir any additional information regarding your sdk. Because it's strange that i have all the latest settings of studio and I still can find it.

Comment: i'll use 4.4 gradle version. i think it's a latest version of gradle

Comment: ok moreover can you check how many SDK update sites are there I have 11.

Comment: hear is also 11

Comment: Can you post your gradle file here. and what are the gradle build tools you are using ?

Comment: in gradle i wast just paste 1 line **`implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'`** other wise all are as it is. See also i'll update my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172581/discussion-between-mohammad-ali-and-umair).